# Doctrine 2 getResult() takes a lot of time

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I work on symfony 2 app using doctrine 2. My code is:

```
$userSites = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT us, s FROM MyMainBundle:UserSite us JOIN us.site s WHERE us.user = :user_id')
            ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
            ->getResult();
```

It returns usually about 7000+ records. When I pass this query directly to mysql (using getSql() and paste to phpmyadmin) it takes 0,008s. But getResult() takes about 20-30 sec. :( Why? Can I speed it up?

Comment: I had this problem but with Doctrine 1. I've solved this switching the hydration mode from object to array.
I think you can do this on Doctrine 2 as well. Try this:
    `$userSites = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQuery('SELECT us, s FROM MyMainBundle:UserSite us JOIN us.site s WHERE us.user = :user_id')->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)->getResult(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);`

Comment: I changed getResult() to getArrayResult(). Now it takes about 5 sec. but I think it is still too long...

Comment: Can you post the query generated by Doctrine so we can check the difference between it and a raw query?

Comment: Are you maybe doing cpu-heavy stuff inside your entities?

Comment: @vsmoraes Even after 5 years, your solution is still relevant!

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that phpmyadmin does a query without LIMIT? By default it would add LIMIT 0, 30 or something like this, and make a pagination. I would say 20-30s is kind of normal if you are working on your local machine, on shared hosting server or VPS it should load up to few times faster because they make use of cache, like apc.

You should never in real world make a query which would return that many results. You should look into batching for doctrine. That's what I use and it works great. Basically you will make more "smaller" queries in a loop. If you need an example how to do this, I can give you the code example.

And also when you make complex queries and time is important, try to use DBAL (database abstraction layer), to avoid having complex objects to make a query.

Answer (score 2):

It's not surprising Doctrine is slower than just using a `mysql_query()`, but 20-30s for 7000 results is way more than I would expect. Maybe you can profile your application, e.g. with xhprof to see which part is consuming unusual amounts of memory/time.

As @vsmoraes points out in the comment you can switch the FETCH_MODE to array. You could also cache the query/result or maybe paginate (fetch only parts of the results, e.g. the 100 per page).